# Títulos H2, H3 y saltos de línea en Grid

Tags: php, css, grid, css-grid-layout

hace poco me pasé a Grid y hay aspectos que se complicaron.

En el esquema que trabajaba incluía un título `H2`, a veces un `H3` y más luego un salto de línea `<br>` y flotaba los *Items* a la izquierda.

Ahora he migrado a:

```
wrapper {display: grid;  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;}
```

Y va de pelos realmente me ha ahorrado tiempo para acomodar las "cajas".

Pero cómo puedo plantear esta interfaz para que los H2 vuelvan a ser títulos que ocupen todo el espacio horizontal luego un
salto de línea y
H3 como sub título que ocupen todo el espacio horizontal, otro
salto de línea y finalmente los 6 ítem

Ahora mismo todo es considerado un elemento más de la grilla, tanto h2, h3 como los ítems ocupan espacio libre uno al lado del otro..

```
echo '<div class="wrapper">';

if ($id_cate !== 0 && $result = $connection->query($sql)) {

    $nombre_categoria    = '';
    $nombre_subcategoria = '';
    $nombre_subnivelcategoria = '';

while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

if ($nombre_categoria !== $myrow['nombre_categoria']){
    $nombre_categoria = $myrow['nombre_categoria'];

    echo '<h2>Categoría</h2>';  

  }    

   if ($nombre_subcategoria !== $myrow['nombre_subcategoria']){
    $nombre_subcategoria = $myrow['nombre_subcategoria'];

    echo '<h3>Sub Categoría</h3>';  

  }       
        $id_prod = $myrow['id_prod'];
        $precio  = $myrow['precio'];
        $nombre  = $myrow['nombre'];
        $fotoprod  = $myrow['filech'];


         echo '<div class="items">';

        echo '<h4">';
        echo '<a href="#">txt</a></h4>';
        echo '<a href="#"><img/></a>';
        echo '<h5>txt</h5>';

        echo '</div>';

        $cont++;
    }

    }
 echo '</div>';
```

El resultado HTML es

```
<div class="wrapper">

<h2>Categoría Primera</h2>

<h3>Subcategoría</h3>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>


<h3>Subcategoría Dos</h3>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<h3>Subcategoría Tres</h3>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Si tu  problema es de grid y no en el PHP, por favor prueba poner un ejemplo con el HTML resultante para que podamos entender que es lo que necesitas

Comment: Sí, gracias. Editado y con ejemplo, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías utilizar `grid-column-start` y `grid-column-end` que definen la posición y la extensión de un elemento dentro del contenedor grid. En este caso quiero que los `h2` y `h3` se extiendan sobre todas 6 columnas

```
h2,h3{ 
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

A lo mejor es esto lo que necesitas.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

h2,h3{ 
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<h2>Categoría Primera</h2>

<h3>Subcategoría</h3>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>


<h3>Subcategoría Dos</h3>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<h3>Subcategoría Tres</h3>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

<div class="item">
<h4>Título</h4>
<a href="#"><img/></a>
<h5>txt</h5>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto enxaneta, gracias hno.!